# How to avoid automatic .tex extension in filenames?

Tags: input, external-files, filesystem-access, attachfile

I am in an mildly unfortunate situation in which, because of the way I prepared the files automatically, I ended up with a file to be attached but also another file with the same name but ending in the `.tex` extension. It seems that when referring to a file inside TeX the file with the extension `.tex` is always preferred. For example:

If I have the files `example.cpp.tex` and `example.cpp` (no `.tex` extension), then with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{attachfile}
\begin{document}
\textattachfile{example.cpp}{link}
\end{document}
```

`attachfile` will attach `example.cpp.tex` instead of `example.cpp`. This seems to be also true for many LaTeX commands, such as `\input`, `\include`, `embedfile` etc.

How can I enforce to use the file specified and not the `.tex` terminated one in general or in particular for `\attachfile`?

(Note: the problem is not the double extension; the unexpected result will also happen with the files `example` and `example.tex`.)

Comment: The _TeXboot_ mentions: _In most installations of TeX, the extension `.tex` will be appended to the file name, as with
`\input`, if no extension is given explicitly_. But this shouldn't affect file names with extensions…

Comment: I would recommend something like [untested] `rename 's/\.cpp\.tex/-cpp.tex/'` in a unix terminal. Much better than trying to fix this through tex

Comment: @Andrey: thanks for pointing that out. I would say that it makes some sense for "\input". But for attachfile? what for, why would it add the .tex extension?

Comment: (many years later) For LuaTeX you can just read the file from Lua.

Comment: @user202729 what do you mean? How?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is as far as I know no way to get around the problem.

How TeX handles files with unusual numbers of dots (where "unusual" is any number unequal to 1) is quite inpredictable and also has changed over time. In miktex 2.4 e.g. `\input{file.cfg}` would have tried at first `file.cfg` then `file.cfg.tex`, in miktex 2.5 it tried only `file.cfg`, in the current 2.9 it tries at first `file.cfg.tex` and then `file.cfg`.

The only advice I can give: Avoid in TeX multiple dots like the plague.

Comment: I agree, however the real issue IMHO are not the multiple dots but having a file `foo.bar` and also `foo.bar.tex`. This constellation should really be avoided. For me TeX Live 2011 always takes `foo.bar.tex` before `foo.bar`, even with the low level `\@@input` primitive.

Comment: The ambiguity between foo.bar and foo.bar.tex only exists because of the multiple dots in one of the file names. If all your files use only one dot the problem can't happen.

Comment: @ulrike's comment: between foo and foo.tex will also prefer foo.tex with \attachfile{foo}, so the double extension is not the problem.

Comment: I've had some luck with appending a `.` for example I have a file called `readme.tex` that inputs a file called `readme` using the input command `\input{readme.}` (Note the dot). This works in MikTeX 2.9 on Windows 10, I can't vouch for other flavours/distributions though. I think it stems from the need to append a dot when creating `.extention` files e.g. one must name the file `.extention.` for it to be called `.extention`, windows strips the dot.

Answer (score 1):

If these files are generated automatically, then I recommend some regex-fu to disambiguate the files. Obviously, depending on exactly what the automatic naming scheme for the files is, you may need to change the pattern, but this should be pretty general.

```
rename 's/\.tex/-tex.tex/' *.tex
```

What this will do is rename each `example.tex` file to `example-tex.tex`. Now doing `\input{example}` will input `example`, not `example-tex.tex`.

OK. So this is a little ugly, but it works. If the files are actually like `example.cpp.tex` then the less ugly renaming would be:

```
rename 's/\.cpp\.tex/-cpp.tex/' *.tex
```

This requires a unix-like terminal or something like [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). Hints in comments for a native windows equivalent regex batch file renamer appreciated.

Comment: thanks, but the filenames are really automatic I didn't want to change that just because some avoidable issue in LaTeX. I was looking for a latex answer to a latex problem. thanks anyway.

Comment: @alfC but if they're automatically generated, why not just generate them with different names? Or rename them in a predictable way? And given that the issue doesn't seem to be avoidable (see the accepted answer) then what other option do you have?

Comment: in the light of these answers... it seems that none other unfortunately. +1