# Read file without file extension from hidden directory

Tags: miktex, filesystem-access

I'm trying to read some data from a file and use the following approach:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand{\file}{./.dir/.testFile}
\begin{document}
\newread\myread
\openin\myread=\file\relax
\loop
  \read\myread to \data
  \unless\ifeof\myread
    \data
  \repeat
\closein\myread
\end{document}
```

This works for the following files (specified in the `\file` macro):

- `testFile.txt` --> Normal file
- `dir/testFile.txt` --> Normal file in folder
- `.dir/testFile.txt` --> Normal file in hidden folder
- `.dir/.testFile`    --> Hidden file in hidden folder

But exactly the case which I need is not working: `.dir/testFile`. Why is it not possible to read a file without file extension and is there a way to get around this? Renaming the file is no option for me as the file is used/modified/created by another application. I need just the first line of the file, if this simplifies the problem in any way.

According to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24773/how-to-avoid-automatic-tex-extension-in-filenames) question/answer, the extension `.tex` is always appended to the file name if no extension is given (even by using low-level commands). But I still think there must be a way to bypass this.

System:

- pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4.1.40.13
- MiKTeX 2.9 (Revision 2.9.4533, 32 bit)
- Windows 7 Professional (64 bit)

Comment: That's weird: I've just try your example, it works fine. I create dir `/tmp/.dir`, move there file `.testFile` with some text and move your latex file into `\tmp`. It compiles. Maybe your problem is with access to that file?

Comment: Now try the same with the file named `testFile` (no extension, not hidden). This is the case which is not working.

Comment: It works in all cases.

Comment: OK, this sounds MiKTeX-specific: I tested with my TeX Live 2013 system, Windows 7 (64-bit), pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 and all was fine. Perhaps you could add your Windows version to the question, and specify 32- or 64-bit MiKTeX (just in case this is relevant).

Comment: I've now set up a MiKTeX test system on my machine: I get the `\data=` prompt when the file does not have an extension whether the folder starts with `.` or not. This is definitely in contrast to TeX Live, but I guess might be a 'system-dependent variation'. Only Christian Schenk can say if it's deliberate.

Comment: for input at least it was supposed to be fixed some years ago: http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/1248/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have MiKTeX to test but it seems that extensionless files for input was fixed with [this bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/1248/).

If `\read` wasn't fixed at the same time, the workaround should probably work: append a `.` to the end of the filename in the TeX call:

```
\newcommand{\file}{./.dir/testFile.}
                                  %
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to solve the Problem and @karlkoeller has explained very well what goes on behind the scene in MiKTex. Before i accept this as answer: How portable is this solution? Will it work with TexLive on Linux for example?

Comment: @jrast don't think it is portable `testfile` and `testfile.` are unrelated filenames on *ix filesystems. Also I think it's a Miktex bug, prior to the latex2e release it was common for tex implementations to use different search algorithms for `\input` and `\read` but we put some effort into getting everyone to use the same so that `\openin` could be used to test if a file exists so `\InputIfFileExists` (and `\input{}`) do the right thing.

Answer (score 7):

The problem arises, if you are using LuaTeX.

The source of the problem is that TeX tries the extension `.tex` for file names without extensions. Thus it seems that LuaTeX *forces* the extensions `.tex` if no extension is given. (A bug-report could be made.)

However, LuaTeX also supports an alternative syntax for specifying file names, similar to `\pdfximage`, the file name can be surrounded by braces, then the correct file is found:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand{\file}{./.dir/testFile}
\begin{document}

\newread\myread
\openin\myread={\file}\relax
\loop
  \read\myread to \data
  \unless\ifeof\myread
    \data
  \repeat
\closein\myread
\end{document}
```

(Tested with LuaTeX 0.76.0 of TeX Live 2013.)

Comment: Sadly this is not working with pdfTex/MiKTex. (I added my system information to the question right now)