# Get return value of `\write18`

Tags: shell-escape

I'm using `\immediate\write18{./somescript.sh}` to execute my own shell script at the beginning of the latex compilation process. Is there a possibility to get the return value afterwards?

Comment: This question has probably been asked before: with `\input{|"someCommand --withOptions and arguments"}` you can `\input` from the standard output of `someCommand --withOptions and arguments`.  This also works with `\openin`.  See also [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249580/69818) that is somehow related.

Comment: Thanks! I searched a bit, but I didn't find anything relevant - maybe because I searched for write18 and not generally shell commands...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A very elementary approach using shell facilities:

Write the script execution state (either of the script itself or of the last command to an external file using `>` redirection and then read this generated file to a `\def\foomacro`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newread\myscriptresult

\begin{document}
\immediate\write18{./myscript.sh; echo $? > scriptresult.txt}
\immediate\openin\myscriptresult=scriptresult.txt
\read\myscriptresult to \ScriptResult
\immediate\closein\myscriptresult

The result was \ScriptResult

\end{document}
```

`myscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -la
```

Comment: It works really nice, but only when use a filename with an extension, e.g. `result.txt`. Without this file extension, the latex compilation process stops, as nothing is read into `\ScriptResult` and a comparison for an `\ifnum` fails. I don't know, if the file extension is somehow mandatory, or I do something wrong... EDIT: probably it's related to me using luatex, and luatex automatically puts a .tex behind an extension-less filename, like described here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128326/44467

Comment: @Faekynn: Please don't edit answers. A comment would have been enough and I would have looked.

Comment: OK! I'll keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 12):

The following MWE show how you can directly `\input` from, say, the `date` command.  It also shows how to `\read` the output of `date` in a control sequence, by means of `\openin`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newread\teststream
\newcommand*\testline{}
\openin\teststream=|date
\ifeof\teststream
    \typeout{Unable to open test stream.}
\else
    \typeout{Test stream opened.}
    \read\teststream to \testline
    \typeout{\testline}
\fi

\begin{document}
\input{|date}
\end{document}
```

However, to avoid problems with special characters, it is probably better to use `\readline` innstead of `\read`, if you are running with e-TeX extensions enabled (as you ordinarily do, nowadays).

Of course, the above code requires that you enable the shell-escape feature.

**Addition**

I think it may be useful to add references to a couple of related (questions and) answers: first of all (and above all) there is [Write18: capturing shell (script) output as command/variable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16790/69818); however, none of the answers to this question (or to [this other, related one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70854/69818)) mention the fact that the “piped input” feature also works with `\openin`.  For this reason, I take the liberty to cite also [Include/input every subfile from a subfolder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/234816/69818), even if it includes an answer by myself (and this surely qualifies as self-promotion, which isn’t very nice -- please be forgiving).

Comment: This solution is nice, but unfortunately not suitable for me: I do want to read the output on the console, and with the other solution I simply added an `echo` before each `exit` to my script...

Comment: The advantage of this solution is the testing if the stream exists. Nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use my [iexec](https://ctan.org/pkg/iexec) package, which checks the exit code automatically. If it's not equal to zero, the compilation will stop with an error:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{iexec}
\begin{document}
\iexec{./my-script.sh}
\end{document}
```

The output of `./my-script.sh` will automatically be included into the document. This can be disabled with `quiet` option:

```
\iexec[quiet]{./my-script.sh}
```