# datetime2's \DTMsavetimestamp can't read from macro - expansion or catcode issue?

Tags: expansion, datetime2

## What already works

I am using `\immediate\write18` to let the GNU `date` command do some date/time arithmetic. The resulting timestamp in ISO format (e.g., `2011-09-09T09:59:59Z`) is written to a temporary file `/tmp/date.txt`, whose content is then read into the macro `\ScriptResult`, which I can happily print. So far so good.

## What *doesn't* work yet

I am then trying to use `\DTMsavetimestamp` from the `datetime2` package to save `\ScriptResult` to a timestamp that I can print via `\DTMusedate` and `\DTMusetime` (both also part of `datetime2`). However, this breaks compilation.

I have absolutely zero doubts that this is due to some expansion-related problem. :)

## Minimal (non-)working example

Save the following file to `test.tex` and try to compile via `pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex` (`-shell-escape` crucial due to `\write18`). Compilation will fail. You can then try to comment the line `\DTMsavetimestamp{mytimestamp}{\ScriptResult}` and uncomment the line `\DTMsavetimestamp{mytimestamp}{2011-09-09T09:59:59Z}`, after which the MWE compiles fine. This is what makes me think that this issue relates to expansion.

```
% NOTE: Compile via: pdflatex -shell-escape

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datetime2}

\begin{document}

\def\mydate{2015-01-01}%
\def\mytime{12:23}%
\def\offset{-7}

% Black magic that works just fine and we should not have to worry about
\immediate\write18{echo '\mydate\space\mytime\space\offset hours' | sed -e 's/://' | xargs -0 date +\%Y-\%m-\%dT\%H:\%M:\%SZ -d > /tmp/date.txt}% 

% Write temporary file content to \ScriptResult. NOTE: Works
% Inspired from: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251574/38212
\newread\myscriptresult
\immediate\openin\myscriptresult=/tmp/date.txt
\read\myscriptresult to \ScriptResult
\immediate\closein\myscriptresult

% Print \ScriptResult. NOTE: Works
\noindent Return value read from \verb|/tmp/date.txt|: \ScriptResult\\

\DTMsavetimestamp{mytimestamp}{\ScriptResult}% TODO: This breaks compilation...
%\DTMsavetimestamp{mytimestamp}{2011-09-09T09:59:59Z}% ... whereas this works.

\noindent Date: \DTMusedate{mytimestamp}\\
\noindent Time: \DTMusetime{mytimestamp}

\end{document}
```

## Restrictions

I am looking for a solution that continues to use the `datetime2` package. If there is a solution that does *not* require writing to a temporary file `/tmp/date.txt`, that would actually be welcome (but it's not a priority).

Comment: Your time is short a second as it's not in the form `HH:MM:SS`.

Comment: I don't understand what offset does in the above... Can you explain?

Comment: I don't think it's an expansion problem. I think it may be a category code problem.

Comment: @Werner: The `\write18` command takes care of the "missing second" and *outputs* an ISO-formatted timestamp, based on the given date, time, and `\offset`, which is interpreted as an offset in hours (that's the date/time arithmetic bit). However, this part works like a charm and should not even have to be understood in detail to solve this problem.

Comment: @FlorianH.: Then try with `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\DTMsavetimestamp{\ScriptResult}}\x`.

Comment: @Werner: `\offset` adds or subtracts a given number of hours to the timestamp defined by `\mydate` and `\mytime`. That's why I need GNU date. Your first solution above bypasses GNU date (and hence the ability to compute the offset). Your second solution gives me a `Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \DTMsavetimestamp was complete.`

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Quite possible; in my restricted TeX universe, expansion and category codes are just two synonyms for compilation hell :) Do you think I should edit the question's title accordingly? Any further pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine using piped input instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datetime2}

\begin{document}

\def\mydate{2015-01-01}%
\def\mytime{12:23}%
\def\offset{-7}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\endlinechar=-1\relax
\edef\pc{\expandafter\@gobble\string\%}
\everyeof{\noexpand}%
\edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\ScriptResult{%
 \@@input|"echo '\mydate\space\mytime\space\offset hours'
   | sed -e 's/://'
   | xargs -0 date +\pc Y-\pc m-\pc dT\pc H:\pc M:\pc SZ -d" }}\x

\makeatother

Result: \ScriptResult

\DTMsavetimestamp{mytimestamp}{\ScriptResult}

\noindent Date: \DTMusedate{mytimestamp}\\
\noindent Time: \DTMusetime{mytimestamp}

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: image of result]

I'm guessing that the writing to file and reading back is introducing a category code change for one or more of the characters that are part of the syntax. The same error occurs if I try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datetime2}

\begin{document}
\edef\ScriptResult{\detokenize{2015-01-01T05:23:00Z}}

Result: \ScriptResult

\DTMsavetimestamp{mytimestamp}{\ScriptResult}

\noindent Date: \DTMusedate{mytimestamp}\\
\noindent Time: \DTMusetime{mytimestamp}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, there's something subtly different in the result when reading in `date.txt` that I haven't noticed.

*Edit:* It's occurred to me that the original problem might have been due to a spurious space added to the end of `\ScriptResult` when reading from `date.txt`, which would probably have caused the same error message.

Comment: This works beautifully, and I'd like to accept it as an answer. However, when I try to move from my MWE to the real-world example, compilation fails for some reason with a `Improper \spacefactor` message. I am guessing this is triggered by `\space`, but I have no idea why the error appears not in my MWE, but only in my larger project. Any ideas? Or if not, perhaps workarounds that do not require `\space` altogether? I should mention that I am *actually* reading `\mydate` and `\mytime` from a `.csv` file via `\usepackage{datatool}` (but that does *not* seem to cause this particular issue).

Comment: Possible pointer to the cause of the `Improper \spacefactor` error: http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-atvert.html

Comment: @FlorianH. Yes, improper space factor often indicates that you're using internal commands (ones with `@` in the name) when `@` is not considered a letter. (That's why my MWE has `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`)

Comment: Mmh, but I *am* using `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` in my real-world project, and still I get that error. Need to investigate further, I guess.

Comment: It turns out that if the `Improper \spacefactor` error is thrown in my real-world project only in presence of `\DTMsavetimestamp{mytimestamp}{\ScriptResult}`. If I comment that command, plus the `\DTMusedate` and `\DTMusetime` commands, the project compiles fine as well. Any ideas?

Comment: It turned out that in my real-world project, I had used the `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` sequence (which Nicola had contributed above) inside an instance of a custom macro of mine. Once I pulled out the `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` such as to envelop the entire macro instance, things compiled just fine. This is what gave me the idea: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201348/why-doesnt-makeatletter-work-inside-newcommand . I'll except Nicola's answer.