# Includegraphics detects wrong fileformat

Tags: graphics

I like to include an image with

```
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{./images/My_Image.svg.png}
```

where the image is an png file that had been converted with inkscape from an svg and therefor the filename-ending is .svg.png on linux.

Now pdflatex does not recognize it as an png

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .svg.png.
```

What can I do, besides renameming the file? 
Renaming does not work, because the files are needed in exacly that name from somewhere else, my last idea would be to use symlinks, but I would prefer a "latex-only" solution

Comment: Try this `\includegraphics[width=5cm]{./images/My_Image}` and let latex figure it out. I agree that it would be nice to have a way to force a format, e.g. `\includegraphics[format=png, ...]{...}` but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: thanks, I tried but it didn't work: it says "file not found" (even there is one .svg and one .svg.png - looks like it only searches for one dot) and extension letters without more dots

Comment: I see. I was always puzzled about how latex handles extensions, for example a similar problem is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24773/how-to-avoid-automatic-tex-extension-in-filenames

Comment: Try loading package `grffile`: the standard LaTeX routine is designed around files with a standard `<filename>.<extension>` format with one `.`; `grffile` extends the code to cover multiple `.` chars in the name.

Comment: Thanks Joseph: your hint worked very well, I would mark this as the accepted answer if possible; Werner: you're right, didnt find it while searching, it looks like there are several ways to solve it, thanks!