# Extension defaults to .tex in VerbatimOut environment

Tags: fancyvrb

When I try to write a file with some name for example `a` (then read it afterwards)

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

.........

\begin{VerbatimOut}{a}
file content here...
\end{VerbatimOut}

% process the file named a
```

I get a file not found error.

After debugging for a little I realize that `VerbatimOut` writes to a file named `a.tex` instead.

The package's documentation `fancyvrb-doc` only mention `VerbatimOut` in a single paragraph and no mention of this behavior.

How can I write to a file without extension? (using a different package is fine.)

---

I'm on an UNIX system so `a` and `a.` (empty extension) is different. Compiler is LuaLaTeX (`This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.0 (TeX Live 2021/Arch Linux)`)

Comment: (I don't actually need this, this is only for future searchers (it's completely natural to type a file name as `a`!). Hopefully they can save some time, or if this is a bug in the package then it can be fixed and they would not encounter it in the first place)

Comment: Also I (conveniently) also named the main TeX file `a.tex`, so I got more hard-to-understand issues.

Comment: Actually, reading `\openout` primitive this is probably inherited from there.

Comment: Related: How TeX prioritize `file.extension.tex` to `file.extension` if the former exists https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24773/250119

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, all present implementations of TeX automatically add `.tex` to file names that lack an extension in the specification, either when opening the file for reading or for writing.

The only “extension-free” implementation I know of was TeXtures, because in MacOS up to version 9 extensions were not used.

So it's essentially impossible to write out a file without an extension in its name.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

The manual doesn't highlight that

```
\begin{VerbatimOut}{file}    % creates file.tex
```

while

```
\begin{VerbatimOut}{file.txt}  % creates file.txt
```

Perhaps it should have done so.

I, like you, have tried to get an extensionless output file but have failed

Comment: I already realized this however, so I decide to ask how to write to extensionless file instead.

Comment: @user202729 Apologies, I misread your question. I think that you right about the `\openout`, used by `VerbatimOut`, adding a file extension if one is not given. Personally I wouldn't go near trying to change that. BTW, I've always used an extension for every file (perhaps just to remind me what it is about but no extension for a directory, so a directory/file name distinction).

Comment: @PeterWilson: `\VerbatimOut`  does nothing special. It is hardcoded in `TeX` ...